# Regex C# Matching string from two words in exact order and returning capture of non-matched words

Tags: c#, regex

C# Regex

I have the following list of strings:

- "New patient, brief"
- "New patient, limited"
- "Established patient, brief"
- "Established patient, limited"
- "New diet patient"
- "Established diet patient"
- "School Physical"
- "Deposition, 1 hour"
- "Deposition, 2 hour"

I would like to separate these strings into groups using regex.

The first pattern I see is:
"New" or "Established"  -- will be the first word of the matched pattern. This word will need to be captured and returned. Of this pattern, "patient" must be present without need to capture. Any word after "patient" must be captured.

I've tried: `((?=.*\bNew\b))(?=.*\bpatient\b)([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)`
but the return match gives:

```
Full match  0-3 `New`
Group 1.    0-0 ``
Group 2.    0-3 `New`
```

Not at all what I am looking for.

```
string input = "New patient, limited";
string pattern = @"((?=.*\bNew\b))(?=.*\bpatient\b)([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
GroupCollection groups = matches[0].Groups;


foreach (Match match in matches)
{
  Console.WriteLine("First word:        {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
  Console.WriteLine("Last words: {0}", match.Groups[2].Value);
  Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Thank you for any help with this.

Edit #1

For strings like "New patient, limited"
output should be:  "New" "limited"

For strings like "Deposition, 1 hour" where "hour" is present, 
output should be: "Deposition, 1 hour"

For strings where there are no words after "patient" but "patient" is present, like
"New diet patient", 
output should be: "New" "diet"

For strings where neither "patient" nor "hour" is present, the entire string should be returned. i.e like "School Physical" should return the entire string,
"School Physical".

As I said, this is my ultimate quest. At the moment, I am trying to focus on separating out only the first pattern :). Much Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the output to be?  I am not seeing a clear example.

Comment: @maccettura Sorry... Will add outputs :)

Comment: Probably, you want [`\b(New|Established)\s+patient\b\W*(.+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28New%7cEstablished%29%5cs%2bpatient%5cb%5cW*%28.%2b%29&i=New+patient%2c+brief)

Comment: Forget about captures... Can you summarize it as a table of `inputString=>expectedOutput`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. That works for the first pattern! So simple a change. Thank you. (Please post as answer so I can credit you :))

Comment: @Eser Making changes now. :)

Comment: Yeah the input / output does not make much sense to me.  Given one single input example, what is the expected output example

Comment: Probably you may get all matches with `^(?:(?!\b(?:New|Established)\b).)*$|\b(New|Established)\s+(?:patient\b\W*)?(.+)` - if Group 1 is not matched, grab `match.Value`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Awesome! It will take some time for me to grasp this. Thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer with a kind of an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
^(?:(?!\b(?:New|Established)\b).)*$|\b(New|Established)\s+(?:patient\b\W*)?(.+)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3A%28%3F!%5Cb%28%3F%3ANew%7CEstablished%29%5Cb%29.%29*%24%7C%5Cb%28New%7CEstablished%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Apatient%5Cb%5CW*%29%3F%28.%2B%29&i=New%20patient%2C%20brief%0D%0ANew%20patient%2C%20limited%0D%0AEstablished%20patient%2C%20brief%0D%0AEstablished%20patient%2C%20limited%0D%0ANew%20diet%20patient%0D%0AEstablished%20diet%20patient%0D%0ASchool%20Physical%0D%0ADeposition%2C%201%20hour%0D%0ADeposition%2C%202%20hour&o=m)

**Details**

- `^(?:(?!\b(?:New|Established)\b).)*$` - any string that has no `New` or `Established` as whole words
- `|` - or
- `\b(New|Established)` - a whole word `New` or `Established` (put into Group 1)
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:patient\b\W*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of `patient` followed with word boundary and 0+ non-word chars
- `(.+)` - Group 2: any 1 or more chars other than line break chars.

The code will look like

```
var match = Regex.Match(s, @"^(?:(?!\b(?:New|Established)\b).)*$|\b(New|Established)\s+(?:patient\b\W*)?(.+)");
```

If Group 1 is not matched (`!match.Groups[1].Success`), grab the whole match, `match.Value`. Else, grab `match.Groups[1].Value` and `match.Groups[2].Value`.

Results:

[image]